# Discount calculation is incorrect

Tags: mysql

I'm sure the order in which I'm doing this is wrong. I have the following calculation:

```
(`p`.`price`*`op`.`quantity`) * ((`p`.`tax_state`+`p`.`tax_fed`)/100) + (`p`.`price`*`op`.`quantity`) * `op`.`discount` as totaldisc,
```

I am multiplying the price and quantity by the tax divided by 100 plus the price and quantity then finally multiplying by the decimal discount amount. When I do this with a calculator, I get the correct discount but with SQL, I'm off by a few dollars.

Comment: Why are you using MySQL to do math? Leave that to the regular code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its issue with the operator precedence. Try this:

```
 (
     (`p`.`price`*`op`.`quantity`) * 
     ((`p`.`tax_state`+`p`.`tax_fed`)/100) + 
     (`p`.`price`*`op`.`quantity`)
 ) * `op`.`discount` as totaldisc,
```

Excerpt from MySQL docs Site:

> Operators that are shown together on
>   a line have the same precedence. 
>   INTERVAL BINARY, COLLATE !
>   - (unary minus), ~ (unary bit inversion) ^
>   *, /, DIV, %, MOD
>   -, + <<, >> & |
>   = (comparison), <=>, >=, >, <=, <, <>, !=, IS, LIKE, REGEXP, IN BETWEEN,
>   CASE, WHEN, THEN, ELSE NOT &&, AND XOR
>   ||, OR
>   = (assignment), :=

For more information on operator precedence check:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: Thanks Cybermate. I'll give that a shot now.

Comment: Yes.. That worked. Thank you. Can you tell me how you determined the precedence? I need to be able to deduce this for myself and quite honestly, I'm not that good at it.

Comment: @jim if this answer solved your problem. Consider marking this as answered by clicking the up-tick sign next to this answer. And if you liked the answer, you may consider giving it an up-vote by clicking up-arrow.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the relevant paste from the manual, Cybermate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving discount on Total price ((price*quantity) + ((price*quantity)+tax/100)) or just on price without tax?

If you are providing discount on price*quantity then its is fine otherwise bracket must be placed before dicount

(  (`p`.`price`*`op`.`quantity`) * ((`p`.`tax_state`+`p`.`tax_fed`)/100) + (`p`.`price`*`op`.`quantity`) ) * `op`.`discount` as totaldisc,